# Analyzing a chemistry experiment - Sampling without replacement

Tags: sampling, hypergeometric-distribution, chemometrics

I've been reviewing the results of an interesting chemistry experiment a colleague of mine was conducting, and she sought some help analyzing the results. Would you be able to help, please?

## The experiment settings

- A set of 1,200 known chemical substances denoted $s_1, s_2, s_3, ..., s_{1200}$. 10 of which are have a specific feature (for example, carcinogenic), and the other 1190 lack this feature.
- A sensor we would like to test. The sensor returns a list of 7 substance ids suspected to be carcinogenic; it should perform significantly better than choosing at random.

## Results

From that list of 7 ids returned from the seonsor, 2 were actually carcinogenic, and 5 were not.

## Analysis

I would like to know is the probability of finding *exactly* 2, or *at least* 2, carcinogenic substances out of the sample, and the [P-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) of the result.

My best guess so far is a [Hypergeometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). In other words,

$P\left(X=k\right) = {{{D \choose k} {{N-D} \choose {n-k}}}\over {N \choose n}}$, Where $n=7, N=1200, D=10, k=2$.

I am not sure how to calculate $P\left(X\geq k\right)$.

## My question

What is the relevant probability distribution and [P-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value) for analyzing the results of such experiment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you would use the Hypergeometric Distribution just calculate $(P = k)$ for $k = 2, 3,....7$ and then sum the results to get $P(X \geq k)$ the probability that X is greater than or equal to k.